# Пауза между нажатиями на кнопку

Tags: android, button

Есть кнопка. Нужно, чтобы при её нажатии в первый раз действие произошло. А при последующих - с интервалом в секунду. То есть нажал - жди секунду, можешь снова нажать. И так далее. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку ставить disable на кнопку, затем выполнять действие, затем поставить таймер на секунду, при срабатывании таймера включить кнопку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean isclicked=false;

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.justButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!isclicked){
            isclicked=true;
            justMethod();
         }
     }
});

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (null != arrayOfList && arrayOfList.size() != 0) {
        TOTAL_ITMES = Integer.parseInt(arrayOfList.get(0).getId());
        for (Item item : arrayOfList) {
            mainArrayList.add(item);
        }
    }
    setAdapterToListview();
    isclicked=false;
}
```

Ну или же можно скрывать кнопку методом `setEnabled()` при нажатии на кнопку, а после выполнения метода делать ее вновь доступной. Хотя, я думаю, все зависит от задачи.
[Возможный повтор вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314315/android-button-disable-multiple-clicks)